# Почему не записывается файл write-ом в linux?

Tags: c, c++, linux

Здравствуйте. Почему не работает write в этом коде?

```
{
    char parent[100];
    printf("Parent starts, id= %dn", getpid());
    if ((fdwt = creat(argv[2], 0666)) == -1)
        exit(1);
    for (;;) {
        if (read(fdrd, &parent, 1) != 1) {
            printf("par dotn");
            break;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 50000; i++); /* Long cycle */
        //write(1,&parent,1);
        write(fdwt, &parent, 20);
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь прочитать файл и выводить по 20 байт в файл (`write (fdwt, &parent, 20);`). Вместо этого выводится какая-то ерунда...

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно, как Вы читаете файл. В строчке

```
if (read(fdrd, &parent, 1) != 1) {
```

все время происходит считывание всех байтов файла и запись их в первый байт массива. В результате массив `parent` содержит что угодно, только не содержимое файла.

Надо бы так

```
int i = 0;
while ( read(fdrd, parent + i, 1) == 1 ) {i++;}
printf("par dotn");
```

и далее по тексту

P.S. А еще лучше сразу определить размер файла (с помощью fstat или seekl) и далее читать его целиком (если это, конечно, не файл символьного устройства)

Еще надо бы делать проверку возвращаемых сисвызовами значений на ошибки.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что 100 байт уместят содержимое файла?

Comment: Задайте просто  100% или лучше определите размер файл и выделите память под него в куче при помощи malloc. Размер стека лимитирован. Можно его, в принципе, увеличить, но лучше использовать кучу.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под кучей? Массив?

Comment: Память я с лихвой под него выделил.... Почему-то он по 10 байт не выводит...

Comment: читаем man 3 malloc

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, как это

    char parent[100];
    ...
    ... read(fdrd, &parent, 1) ...
    write(fdwt, &parent, 20);


вообще скомпилировалось (**&parent**)


Даже если код чуть другой (например $parent[0]), то все равно ошибка - читаем по **одному байту**, а пишем **по 20**.

Вообще-то правильно писать ровно столько, сколько прочли read-ом.

--

@mikillskegg, а зачем Вы советуете (и демонстрируете в `while`) читать весь файл в память? Тогда уж показали бы человеку `mmap`.